# R - How to create a histogram based on time with regards to sign changing values from my table?

Tags: r, histogram, sign

I have the following [image: database]. What I would like to do is a histogram that will show me the time of the sign change of my value. For instance, having the bellow database, I want to create a table that will show me that that for the first hour the value stayed positive, afterward the table should show me that the sign was negative for 11 hours and so on.

In the end, I want to obtain a histogram that will show me that for 1h I had positive value, afterward for 11 hours I had negative values and so on.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
d                          Substract
"2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"  228.37
"2017-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"  -986
"2017-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" -700
"2017-01-01 03:00:00 UTC"   -1940
"2017-01-01 04:00:00 UTC"  -1941
"2017-01-01 05:00:00 UTC"   -1982
"2017-01-01 06:00:00 UTC"    -1738
"2017-01-01 07:00:00 UTC"    -1414
"2017-01-01 08:00:00 UTC"    -1414
"2017-01-01 09:00:00 UTC"   -313
"2017-01-01 10:00:00 UTC"  -1230
"2017-01-01 11:00:00 UTC"   -1067
"2017-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"  577
```

Answer (score 0):

First I create a variable that identifies and labels whether tour variable is positive or negative, then plot the histogram. There you go

```
library(ggplot2)

foo = read.table(text = 'd                          Substract
"2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"  228.37
                 "2017-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"  -986
                 "2017-01-01 02:00:00 UTC" -700
                 "2017-01-01 03:00:00 UTC"   -1940
                 "2017-01-01 04:00:00 UTC"  -1941
                 "2017-01-01 05:00:00 UTC"   -1982
                 "2017-01-01 06:00:00 UTC"    -1738
                 "2017-01-01 07:00:00 UTC"    -1414
                 "2017-01-01 08:00:00 UTC"    -1414
                 "2017-01-01 09:00:00 UTC"   -313
                 "2017-01-01 10:00:00 UTC"  -1230
                 "2017-01-01 11:00:00 UTC"   -1067
                 "2017-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"  577', header = T)

foo$n_sign = ifelse(foo$Substract >0, 'positive', 'negative')

ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = n_sign)) + geom_histogram(stat = 'count') + labs(y = 'n_hours')
```

[image]